# Trying Elasticsearch with Shield to kibana dashboard Getting Error?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-shield

The following sample data I haved used in my environment

**Data:**

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "cases", "_type" : "case", "_id" : "101" } }
{ "admission" : "2015-01-03", "discharge" : "2015-01-04", "injury" : "broken arm" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "cases", "_type" : "case", "_id" : "102" } }
{ "admission" : "2015-01-03", "discharge" : "2015-01-06", "injury" : "broken leg" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "cases", "_type" : "case", "_id" : "103" } }
{ "admission" : "2015-01-06", "discharge" : "2015-01-07", "injury" : "broken nose" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "cases", "_type" : "case", "_id" : "104" } }
{ "admission" : "2015-01-07", "discharge" : "2015-01-07", "injury" : "bruised arm" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "cases", "_type" : "case", "_id" : "105" } }
{ "admission" : "2015-01-08", "discharge" : "2015-01-10", "injury" : "broken arm" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "patients", "_type" : "patient", "_id" : "101" } }
{ "name" : "Adam", "age" : 28 }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "patients", "_type" : "patient", "_id" : "102" } }
{ "name" : "Bob", "age" : 45 }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "patients", "_type" : "patient", "_id" : "103" } }
{ "name" : "Carol", "age" : 34 }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "patients", "_type" : "patient", "_id" : "104" } }
{ "name" : "David", "age" : 14 }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "patients", "_type" : "patient", "_id" : "105" } }
{ "name" : "Eddie", "age" : 72 }
```

**Indexed the data into the node**

```
$ curl -X POST 'http://localhost:9200/_bulk' --data-binary @./hospital.json


[2015-02-12 08:18:01,347][INFO ][shield.license ] [node0] enabling license for [shield]
[2015-02-12 08:18:01,347][INFO ][license.plugin.core ] [node0] license for [shield] - valid
[2015-02-12 08:18:01,355][ERROR][shield.license ] [node0]
#
# Shield license will expire on [Saturday, March 14, 2015]. Cluster health, cluster stats and indices stats operations are
# blocked on Shield license expiration. All data operations (read and write) continue to work. If you
# have a new license, please update it. Otherwise, please reach out to your support contact.
#
```

**Installed Shield and started as the above**

The data is protected and I can see like below if i'm trying to access.

```
$ curl localhost:9200/cases/case/101?pretty=true
{
    "error" : "AuthenticationException[missing authentication token for REST request [/cases/case/1]]",
    "status" : 401
}
```

User and roles are added like below

```
$ elasticsearch/bin/shield/esusers useradd alice -r nurse
$ elasticsearch/bin/shield/esusers useradd bob -r doctor
```

I have edited the roles.yml and tried to add doctor and nurse according to the eg mentioned above. The security is not worked for me.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-142-247-183:~/elkproject/elasticsearch-1.4.4/config/shield$ curl --user alice:abc123 localhost:9200/_count?pretty=true
{
"error" : "AuthenticationException[unable to authenticate user [alice] for REST request [/_count?pretty=true]]",
"status" : 401
}
```

Note : I referred this blog http://blog.trifork.com/2015/03/05/shield-your-kibana-dashboards/
Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Did you install elasticsearch from a package (like a RPM or DEB)? If so, there may be an issue with the esusers tool putting the users in the wrong place. Right now, you have to [configure your environment](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/getting-started.html#_configuring_your_environment) with the right location and add the users. If this is the case, you can move the $ES_HOME/config/shield directory to /etc/elasticsearch, which is the default configuration directory for RPM and DEB installations. When using the esusers commands in the future, just make sure the environment variables are set like shown in the link.

You can also remove Shield and start the install over following the full [getting started guide](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/getting-started.html) and then start modifying the files as mentioned in the blog. To remove the existing Shield install: `bin/plugin -r shield`

Comment: I installed elastic search with tar file and not deb or rpm.

Comment: @prem I see. That just tends to be one common problem, so I thought of it first. Can you share your elasticsearch.yml file or at least any modifications? Also, in the $ES_HOME/config/shield/users file, do the user entries exist?